# jQuery hide/show a div

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my HTML structure.

```
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Now when I hide the `content` div, using `$("#content").hide`, my footer block comes up. I want that my footer block should be remain fixed at the bottom, even if I hide it or show it.

How can I do it?

Comment: just set it position:fixed; bottom:0;

Comment: `$('#content').css('visibility','hidden')`

Comment: you should show you JS as well. Plus, `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are different.

Comment: whatever part of JS was required, was shown. I dont think any extra information should be provided to understand the question better

Comment: @putvande - Then how do I set the visibility to show again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: none` and `visibility: hidden` are different.

If you choose `display: none`, the DIV will no longer occupying the space, thus the footer will come up.

Therefore, you should use (as per @putvande said in comment):

```
$('#content').css('visibility','hidden')
```

If you set `visibility: hidden`, the DIV will be hidden (invisible), but it still occupies the space, as its `display` CSS is still `display: block` by default.

To show the contents again, set:

```
$('#content').css('visibility','visible')
```

Moreover, normally footer uses `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` to fix it to the bottom of the page, which will probably avoid the issue you encounter right now.

Comment: added in answer, just use `visible` value

Comment: Hello. I've Highcharts inside the the div `content` . So when I give `$('#content').css('visibility','visible')` command, it removes the div in Chrome and Safari, but some imprints of Highcharts are remained  in Firefox. See this http://jsfiddle.net/zkbb4/ on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide(), use:

```
css('visibility','hidden')
```

hide() sets the display style to none, which completely removes the element from the document flow and causes it to not take up space.

visibility:hidden keeps the space as it is.

and

you can show by javacript event action.For example

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="content">
  here is the content div
</div>
<script>
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#content" ).show( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above scenario, You should write **css** for footer as below,

```
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;    
}
```

You could change the **top** property value according to your requirement.

Kindly refer the below JsFiddle link,

http://jsfiddle.net/rrmrX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
head {position: fixed;top: 0}
footer {position: fixed;bottom: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
you can use this sytax
$("#idContent).toggle();
or
you cant write event click after call funtion use it
$("#idContent").hide();
$("#idContent").show();
```